# Stop and re-run a thread inside itself

Tags: java, multithreading, try-catch, runnable

I have a thread implemented inside a class using runnable like this:

```
static Runnable myThread = new Runnable() {
 public void run(){
  try{
  //do something forever 
  }catch(Exception e){
    //something happened. Re-run this thread
  }
 } 
}
```

I want to keep running this thread even when an exception is found. So, how can i do that inside the exception clause? Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Is there a loop inside the try? Can't it be outside the try-catch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
static Runnable myThread = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    for (;;) {
      try {
        ...
      } catch(Exception e) {
        ...
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Whatever you do, I'd strongly encourage you to not silently ignore the exception. If there's no better way to handle the exception, at the very least log it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a while and continue loop.  Something like:

```
public void run() {
   while (true) 
      try {
          // do something forever 
      } catch(Exception e) {
         // something happened. Re-run this thread
        continue;
      }
      ...
   }
}
```